# import third party JS library in open source LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, third-party

After wasting significant amount of time on how to import jQuery,
I got below 2 ways
in HTML with local path or CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

IN JS with local path or CDN:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But unfortunately both of the above methods won't work in LWC and there is no documentation available on how to do the same.

Below approach works fine in my index.html page to import jQuery in my lwc project.

```
<script src="./resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

I also wasted so many hour on how to import CSS in lwc as there is no documentation available on importing third party CSS also but some how I manged to import css by using below code

```
constructor() {

    super();

    const styles = document.createElement('link');
    styles.href = './resources/css/bootstrap.css';
    styles.rel = 'stylesheet';
    this.template.appendChild(styles);
}
```

So I tried some similar approach to import JS and this doesn't give any errors at the console log but the same doesn't work at all, tried in both constructor and connectedCallback but no luck.

```
connectedCallback() {
        const jq = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
        jq.src = './resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js';
        jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        this.template.appendChild(jq);
    }
```

if anyone has any idea about how to import the JS library in open source LWC then please do let me know, would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: LWC creates a shadow DOM that won’t play well with any library that manipulates the dom.

Comment: in open source LWC also?

Comment: in open source LWC you will need to include `lwc:dom="manual"`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not sure on how to import third party LWC in JS and where to mention lwc:dom="manual"

Comment: Take a look at: https://lwc.dev/guide/javascript_third_party_library

Comment: yes, I have seen this already, in my case I have jquery.js in my local file system and my question is how to import the jQuery.js in my app.html

Comment: in the documentation it is nowhere mentioned how to import .js from the local file system.

Comment: in the source code of the `libsD3.js`, you will see that it is importing it using webpack.

Comment: I would request you to please post an answer on how to do the same with jQuery.

Comment: You'll need to import jquery as a module somehow, either with the `import` or with `require`. Sorry I don't have a direct answer as I've not done it myself, but if I were going to, that's how I'd start.

Comment: It would still be fine if it won't work but would you please post an answer on how can I use require or import

Comment: and for import should I npm jquery ?

Comment: in salesforce specific LWC we have platform specific loadscript method to load the imported js but how would I do the same here, load script won't be available here

Comment: I have updated my question and by any chance is there any alternate of "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [open source LWC recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss)

1. First you need to install [jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) in lwc web-app using `npm install jquery`. OR any other library you want to use. After installation, you will see the file in `node_modules` folder
2. Now, you just need to get that library variable wherever you need. Note that although you can use jquery, you cannot identify the elements directly. i.e., you cannot use `jQuery('p')`, instead you should use `jq(this.template.querySelector('p'))`.

Below is the example from hello world in same sample recipes:

hello.html:

```html
<template>
    
    <button onclick={hide}>Hide</button>
    <button onclick={show}>Show</button>
    
    <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
    
    <ui-card title="Hello">
        <div>
            Hello, {greeting}!
        </div>

        <recipe-view-source source="recipe/hello" slot="footer">
            Bind an HTML element to a component property.
        </recipe-view-source>
    </ui-card>
</template>
```

hello.js:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'World';
    
    connectedCallback(){
        window.jq = require('jQuery');
    }

    hide(){
        jq(this.template.querySelector('p')).hide();
    }

    show(){
        jq(this.template.querySelector('p')).show();
    }
}
```

As many libraries use `$` as default, I just tend to use `jq` for jquery.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response on it,  but still this didn't solve my real problem, I have started a new thread on where exactly jQuery is needed, would you please be kind to take a look to this new thread "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316932/bootstrap-carousel-is-not-sliding-in-open-source-lwc"