# How can I load jQuery in LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, aura, jquery, lightning-components

For the convenience of the user, I'm implementing the requirement of katakana is automatically entered when entering hiragana or kanji in Japanese using [this JavaScript library.](https://github.com/harisenbon/autokana)

You can check the behavior described above at [this URL](https://a.cl.ly/rRuojDqj).

That external JavaScript depends on jQuery, so I have to use jQuery.
First, I'm importing jQuery and trying to see whether it can be used.

I'm trying with a custom component (LWC) in Experience Cloud (Community Cloud).

[This Url](https://demo1-k010c1232-developer-edition.na110.force.com/s/withexternallibraries) is my testing community page.

As it, I mentioned before, the question that can't be loaded, but it seems that jQuery doesn't work on the loaded page.

Here is my code to load jQuery at my custom component(LWC).

```
renderedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, jQueryUrl + '/jquery-3.5.1.min.js')
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`jQuery loaded.`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`jQuery loading was failed.`);
      });
  }
```

I tried window.jQuery in the Chrome developer console, but it didn't seem to reference to jQuery.You can check the behavior at [this Url.](https://a.cl.ly/QwukAoyb)

I confirmed that it is displayed as follows in the developer tools of chrome.You can also check the script tag at [my testing community page's](https://demo1-k010c1232-developer-edition.na110.force.com/s/withexternallibraries) in <head> tag.

```
<script data-locker-src="/resource/***/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean "can't load"? The more details we have, the better we can help you.

Comment: First, are you sure you need it and if so share the reason.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @sfdcfox. I added my additional info to share with you.Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @keith-c. I added my additional info to share with you.Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is that LWC is loading libraries within your specific component and isolates it from outside.

So if you try to use it inside the component, you'll be able to write something like `$('input')`, but window.jQuery in developer console will produce `undefined`.

Hopefully, this helps.

**UPDATE**:
You can access $ after callback on jQuery loaded. In your code you're trying to call jQuery on renderedCallback when it's not yet loaded.

Try something like this

```
            connectedCallback() {
                Promise.all([i.loadScript(this, t + "/jquery-3.5.1.min.js").then(()=>{
                    console.log("jQuery loaded."),
                    i.loadScript(this, l + "/jquery.autoKana.js").then(()=>{
                        console.log("autoKana loaded")
                        this.usejQuery();
                    }
                    ).catch(a=>{
                        console.log("autoKana was not loaded. error is " + a)
                    }
                    )
                }
                ).catch(a=>{
                    console.log("jQuery loading was failed.")
                }
                )])
            }


            usejQuery() {
                console.log($(".li-kanji").val()),
                $.fn.autoKana(".li-kanji", ".li-furigana", {
                    katanaka: !0
                })
            }
            renderedCallback() {
            }
            handleLiKanji(a) {
                this.liKanji = a.target.value
            }
            handleIKanji(a) {
                this.iKanji = a.target.value
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I can't use $('input').val() inside the component. You can check the source at my testing community site resource. How can I use it inside the component? @ytiq

Comment: added update according to your code, use jQuery after callback. You can also add property like jQueryLoaded to component

Comment: $ ('.input').val () remains unavailable directly from within the component, but I was able to resolve it with `this.template.querySelector ()`. Thanks for your help and hints.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to loadScript call using async connectedCallback as per below?

```js
async connectedCallback() {
        try {
            await loadScript(this, `${jQuery_bundle}/jquery.min.js`);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure out how to mark this question as a duplicate.  But I suspect the answer you need is on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279897/best-way-to-use-jquery-on-lighting-web-components).

For visibility here: Salesforce-sas gave the answer:

Firstly, if you are absolutely sure that you cannot get the needed functionality using [standard Javascript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_javascript) and [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/) classes, only then you should go for [Using Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library).

**Option 1:** You should use import statements in every component that need to use this library.

**Option 2:** You use import these libraries in base class and extend that class in every component that needs these libraries.

```
import MyBase from 'c/myBase';

export default class MyComp extends MyBase {
    ...
}
```